After I update my Samsung A14 to android 14, Play Store says that many apps are not compatible, even google apps like Chrome, YouTube, and Google Maps
Recently apps like X/Twitter, Uber, Instagram, Facebook, Pinterest, Spotify, YouTube, Google Chrome, Google Maps, and many others are said to be not available for my device, which is really odd.
The Play Store says that they are not compatible with the version of my android. I'm aware that the new android 14 has the targetSDK policy that blocks old apps to be installed, but this would only be the case if it was old apps, but as you can see that's not the case.
So, I don't know if this is some sort of bug/issue of the Samsung's version of android 14 or is a bug from the Google's Play Store. I'm looking for any information about it that can help me to fix this problem.
Right now, I can only update some of these apps through the Galaxy Store, but not all of them are available there, like the Google apps that I mentioned.
Info:

Device: Samsung A14 5G (SM-A145MZKGZTO)
Android version: 14
Play Store version: 41.1.19-31 [0] [PR] 636190750


I tried that before, and it didn't work, but then I tried again, and now it's working. Thanks.

If Google Play Store behaves oddly often Google Play Store app or Google Play Services have problems.
My recommendation is to clear app data and and uninstall updates for both:

Google Play Store (package name com.android.vending)
Google Play Services (package name com.google.android.gms)

Usually after a time they should fetch and install their latest version and - as long as the latest version doesn't is buggy - everything should work again.
